# What is a more gentle word for "hypervigilant?

Tags: synonyms

What is a More gentle way to say hypervigilant?

Comment: I use meticulous or persevering.

Comment: hmm.... a more gentle way would be to call them "vigilant' .   Perhaps "vigilant to a fault" ?

Comment: @Tom22 Would that still work considering hypervigilance is related to PTSD?

Comment: @lux to the extent I have a point, it is that if someone meant 'hyper' something, 'hyper' is probably the best word for it.  Alternatives would tend to underplay the extreme.  'To a fault' would would suggest some obsessiveness without questioning their character or sanity to strongly. The OP didn't share much intent, but if given that PTSD example someone might want to say they were 'stranded in a hyper-vigilant state' ... or words that might excuse rather than downplay the extreme.  "obsessively vigilant" might be softer and yet still convey over the top.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *focused* might do the trick?

Here are a few of the things [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/focus) says about the words **focus** or **focused**:

> a state or condition permitting clear perception or understanding,
>   directed attention :  emphasis, a center of activity, attraction, or
>   attention, a point of concentration.

Comment: I am reviewing posts and this is the third or fourth of your answers that has been flagged for deletion as low quality. You clearly need to learn how SE EL&U works. At SE we're looking for answers that provide some explanation and context as explained [in the Help, here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Otherwise how can anyone judge if your answer is correct? We only have your word to go on it. As I mentioned, answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: I just joined a few days ago, I am still learning. I will try to beef up my answer.

Comment: David, is that better?

Comment: Yes, that's the sort of thing. It's probably best to use the quotation markup (“” on the toolbar) to enclose the quote from MW and to link back using the []() or other markup. I'll do this for you as an illustration — delete it if you don't like it. And be sure you don't just leave the quote to do the work — see [the referencing help](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).